# Shell function to grep count from two host and return the sum of wc

Tags: bash, shell

I have written one shell script that logs into two host and grep a word in both the server on a particular path. I need to assign the output of the grep to a variable and return the output.
PFB my function

```
f_count ()
{
ssh ebi@hostname_A /bin/bash <<EOF
v_id=$1
cd /var/log/cluster/
add=$(grep -ri $v_id . | wc -l)
echo $add
exit
EOF
ssh ebi@hostname_B /bin/bash <<EOF
v_id=$1
cd /var/log/cluster/
add2=$(grep -ri $v_id . | wc -l)
echo $add2
exit
EOF
sum=$add+$add2
echo $sum
}
```

I want the sum variable to be returned by the above function. 
I have tried the above code but i am not getting any output from the $add, $add2, $sum variables. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea of what you have to do:

```
get_host_count () {
   ssh ebi@"$1" "grep -ri '$2' /var/log/cluster/ | wc -l"
}

f_count() {
   echo $(($(get_host_count hostname_A $1) + $(get_host_count hostname_B $1)))
}
```

**Note:** not tested

Your mistakes:

- you don't capture the output of the ssh, the add variables you define
  are defined on the server side, and they won't get to the client
- you don't use the proper syntax for bash expressions `$(())`
- you shouldn't pipe input blindly to bash/ssh, use `-c` if you need to run a shell

Comment: `grep -c`  then remove the `| wc -l`

Comment: @Jetchisel: that works for a single file if you `grep -h` _or_ use redirection _or_ `cut -d: -f2` or similar, but not with `grep -r` where it produces multiple per-file counts not one total

Comment: The `bash -c` seems uncalled for, and you seem to be missing a single quote.

Comment: @tripleee, without the bash -c all the resulting lines would be brought on the client side, if there are many matches, that would mean a lot of data transferred unnecessarily

Comment: Just `ssh ebi@"$1" "grep -ri '$2' /var/log/cluster/ | wc -l"` would already accomplish that. There is no Bash-specific code here. (Notice the added quotes though.)

Comment: @tripleee, from the ssh manual "If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell", so I always assumed a shell is necessary for piping, however I did a quick test and it seems you are right

Comment: @tripleee looked up the code - it uses the user's shell to execute the command - https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/849a9b87144f8a5b1771de6c85e44bfeb86be9a9/session.c#L1708 -- I learned something today, thanks

Comment: Yeah, there's always the problem that some users have a nonstandard shell; I suppose I agree with the decision that `ssh` should run the user's preferred shell but it's a caveat for portability, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The line in you script

```
sum=$add+$add2
```

should be rewrited as

```
sum=$(( $add + $add2 ))
```

Comment: `$add` are not defined on the client side

Comment: @Sorin, the OP ask how to sum, the rest is his/her responsibility

Comment: "I have tried the above code but i am not getting any output from the $add, $add2, $sum variables. Please advise." - this is from the Question.  it seems to me that he is asking for more than a sum

Answer (score -4):

You can also try

```
sum=`expr $add + $add2 `
```

Comment: No Bash script should require `expr`; Bash has built-in replacements for all the functionality provided by that legacy tool. Backtick syntax is obsolescent and should be avoided in favor of the modern POSIX `$(command substitution)` syntax.